# React/Material Hiding an element's child when it is hovered over using withStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want the ListItemSecondaryAction element with the class actions to be hidden when I hover over the ListItem with the class friendsListItem.

I have tried using the decedent selector within styles but it does not work.

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  friendsListItem: {
    '&:hover $actions': {
      visibility: 'hidden'
    },
  },
  actions: {},
  iconButton: {},
  moreVertIcon: {},
});
```

```
      <List>
          <ListItem button key="Joe" className={classes.friendsListItem}>
              <ListItemSecondaryAction className={classes.actions}>
                <IconButton className={classes.iconButton}>
                  <MoreVertIcon className={classes.moreVertIcon}/>
                </IconButton>
            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
          </ListItem>
      </List>
```

Entire code pastebin if needed: https://pastebin.com/4neuJRki

I would expect the ListItemSecondaryActions to disappear when I hover over the ListItem, but nothing happend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `ListItemSecondaryAction` it changes the structure of the `li` element in a somewhat surprising fashion.

Without the secondary action you have a structure like the following:

```
<li class="list-item-classname">
   whatever is in your ListItem
</li>
```

but **with** the secondary action you get something more like:

```
<li class="container-classname">
   <div class="list-item-classname">
      whatever is in your ListItem
   </div>
   <div class="secondary-action-classname">
      whatever is in your secondary action
   </div>
</li>
```

The important part to notice about the structure above is that the ListItem class is applied to a sibling of the secondary action and not to an ancestor. In order to apply a class to the parent `li` element, you need to specify the `container` class.

From https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/#css:

> container -- Styles applied to the `container` element if `children` includes `ListItemSecondaryAction`.

Here's the syntax for this:

```
        <ListItem
          button
          key="Joe"
          classes={{ container: classes.friendsListItem }}
        >
```

[image: Edit Hide secondary action on hover]